# Marshal and Unmarshal generic object with defined object

Tags: jaxb, jersey, cxf, jackson

I basically want to write pojos to marshal and unmarshal json like,

```
    {
        "unknownkey": known.class,
        "other-unknownkey": known.class
    }
```

if I know what keys those are then I can simply write a jaxb entity like,

```
    @XmlRootElement
    public knownWrapper {
            public known unknownkey;
    }
```

but I don't know the keys before hand and I also don't know how many there are.

Comment: Is the type of key unknown or the count of keys is unknown?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type of objects coming in, then you're probably better of taking it as a String in Jersey, parse it with a JSON parser like http://www.json.org/java/index.html and then introspect the object you're getting using that API.